# How do I achieve this using firebase 9 push?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I switch to firebase 9 and want to achieve following

```
customers
   -MomOdRNzkqr9vDk_MmE:"ptwXJ7JRAASFgd3KoS2fQyQhyV613"
   -Myb3b_2W-7FTlsZvXCO:"QZOQ43DGYwfu4djlZ5EjEVksOr53"
```

I am trying the following

```
const customerSelectedRef = ref(db,`/serviceProvider/${user1.uid}/moneyCollector/customers`);
const customerSelectedRefPush = push(customerSelectedRef);
set(customerSelectedRefPush, customerSelected); // not wanted to use {customerSelected} which gives key value pair under push id
```

How could add value directly to push id?

[image: 1]

The old method was

```
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`/serviceProvider/${user1.uid}/moneyCollector/customers`)
    .push(customerSelected)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Data set.moneyCollector cutomer added");
      checkdubArray = [];
    });
```

Where push id acts as key for `customerSelected`
and I try to get same result in firebase 9.
Dont want the result which I have marked as cross

Comment: Is `customerSelected` an object (can you log it and share output)? If yes, then make sure you are passing the string value only to push as in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the string value directly in `push()` along with the `DatabaseReference` as shown below:

```
const customerSelectedRef = ref(db,`/service/${user1.uid}/Collector/customers`);

await push(customerSelectedRef , "string_value") // Not object
```

The result would be:

[image]

Comment: Thnx works fine was looking at f9 but haven't found this.